# How to change the video displaying orientation in expo-av?

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-av

I'm using [`expo-av`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/video/) to display videos. The videos are played in `Portrait` and i'm trying to display the video depending on the **device orientation**. My code is :

```js
import { Video } from 'expo-av';
import * as ScreenOrientation from 'expo-screen-orientation';
import NavigationHelper from '../../../../Helpers/NavigationHelper';

export default class VideoScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    const { route } = this.props;
    const { videoUri } = route.params;

    if (!videoUri) {
      NavigationHelper.back();
    }

    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <Video
          source={{ uri: videoUri }}
          rate={1.0}
          volume={1.0}
          isMuted={false}
          resizeMode={Video.RESIZE_MODE_CONTAIN}
          shouldPlay
          isLooping
          useNativeControls
          style={{ width: 300, height: 300, alignSelf: 'center' }}
          onReadyForDisplay={() => { const naturalSize = ScreenOrientation.Orientation.PORTRAIT ? { orientation: 'portrait' } : { orientation: 'landscape' }; }}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

I've seen that `onReadyForDisplay` is  function to be called when the video is ready for display. The function is passed a dictionary with the following key-value pairs:
`naturalSize`: a dictionary with the following key-value pairs:
`orientation`: a string describing the natural orientation of the video data, either `portrait` or `landscape`.  I've used `expo-screen-orientation` to get the device orientation.

How can i rotate the video depending on the device orientation ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try it

```
import { Video, VideoFullscreenUpdateEvent } from 'expo-av';
import * as ScreenOrientation from 'expo-screen-orientation';

    
  export const onFullscreenUpdate = async ({
      fullscreenUpdate,
    }: VideoFullscreenUpdateEvent) => {
      if (fullscreenUpdate === Video.FULLSCREEN_UPDATE_PLAYER_DID_PRESENT) {
        await ScreenOrientation.unlockAsync();
      } else if (fullscreenUpdate === Video.FULLSCREEN_UPDATE_PLAYER_WILL_DISMISS) {
        await ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(
          ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.PORTRAIT,
        );
      }
    };


    <Video
       source={{
           uri: videoUrl,
        }}
           onFullscreenUpdate={onFullscreenUpdate}
          ...
```